# prevent all images from loading, just load image which is visible in screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

i have write one script to prevent all image to load directly on page.

```
<div id="domo">
<img src="PUT_YOUR_VALUE"></br>
<img src="PUT_YOUR_VALUE"></br>
<img src="PUT_YOUR_VALUE"></br>
<img src="PUT_YOUR_VALUE"></br>
</div><script>
    var images = document.querySelectorAll("#domo img"), item;
    [].forEach.call(images, function (item) {
        item.setAttribute("data-src", item.src);
        item.removeAttribute("src");
    });
</script>
```

Now i want to load this images if they are visible in view port

i have try but fails, below is java script just add images above script and check

```
<script>
    var images = document.querySelectorAll("#domo img"), item;
    [].forEach.call(images, function (item) {
        item.setAttribute("data-src", item.src);
        item.removeAttribute("src");
    });
    function isElementInViewport(el) {
        var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        return (
            rect.top >= 0 &&
            rect.left >= 0 &&
            rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
            rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
        );
    }
    //these handlers will be removed once the images have loaded
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", lazyLoadImages);
    window.addEventListener("load", lazyLoadImages);
    window.addEventListener("resize", lazyLoadImages);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", lazyLoadImages);

    function lazyLoadImages() {
        var images = document.querySelectorAll("#domo img[data-src]"), item;
        // load images that have entered the viewport
        [].forEach.call(images, function (item) {
            if (isElementInViewport(item)) {
                item.setAttribute("src", item.getAttribute("data-src"))
                item.removeAttribute("data-src")
            }
        })
        // if all the images are loaded, stop calling the handler
        if (images.length == 0) {
            window.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", lazyLoadImages);
            window.removeEventListener("load", lazyLoadImages);
            window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyLoadImages);
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyLoadImages);
        }
    }
</script>
```

i think problem is in `if (isElementInViewport(item)) {` if you get something please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Don't change the images with JS**

Don't change the `img` tag attributes with JS after page loading! The problem of changing the `src` to `data-src` is, whenever your script is executed too late, the browser already started loading the images. So your lazy loading would not work properly. Always create the correct element on page rendering.

```
<div id="domo">
  <img src="" data-src="PUT_YOUR_VALUE"></br>
  <img src="" data-src="PUT_YOUR_VALUE"></br>
  <img src="" data-src="PUT_YOUR_VALUE"></br>
  <img src="" data-src="PUT_YOUR_VALUE"></br>
</div>
```

**2. Use an existing library for lazy loading**

Of course you can try to do everything on your own. But there are plenty of available plugins and libraries out there, doing what you want, with way more options too. The advantage of these are, they are mostly well tested and have a wide browser support. So don't do everything again. ;)

**3. An example**

This said we can create a working example, like with [`jQuery.Lazy`](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/). We just need this plugin and the mentioned changes of point #1.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#domo img").lazy();
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.lazy/1.7.3/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>

<div id="domo">
  <img src="" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000000/fff&text=1">
  <img src="" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000000/fff&text=2">
  <img src="" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000000/fff&text=3">
  <img src="" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000000/fff&text=4">
</div>
```